# Which word event I need to get page settings changed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

which word event I need to notice if the page size or the page orientation of the active document is changed?
In my Add-in I want to react on this changes.

Thx

Comment: I'm wondering about the same. Have you found any useful information about this since your post?

Comment: no sry. I solved my problem in a different way...